GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/mathjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I tried to link mathjs to my script but got this error:
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/mathjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I use local node server
Server code:
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
   
http.createServer(function(request, response){
       
    let filePath = request.url.substring(1);
    if(filePath == "") filePath = "index.html"; 
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, data){
               
        if(error){
            response.statusCode = 404;
            response.end("Resourse not found!");
        }   
        else{
            if(filePath.endsWith(".js")) response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
            response.end(data);
        }
    });
}).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started at 3000");
});

My project strucutre:
Project structure
I tried to correct path, but this didn't help (path was correct?)
import {evaluate} from './node_modules/mathjs';

there is only a folder "node_modules/mathjs". you are probably looking for some exact file. like ""node_modules/mathjs/inex.js", or whatever is there. But the whole approach isn't following modern best practices. usually there is a bundler (for example vite) doing the bundle.js for you to then run the code in the browser and this way the resolution of modules works just fine

Security Warning: If you run this, put ../s into request url path, you have access to any file.

First comment help me solve this problem, thx so musch

You seem to be using commonjs syntax in your server code provided. But import {evaluate} from './node_modules/mathjs'; is es6 syntax, you should rather be using var evaluate = require('./node_modules/mathjs').evaluate;
